# Poor animation performance transitioning to UIViewController (via UINavigationController) and not sure why

Tags: iphone, performance, uiviewcontroller, core-graphics, nib

I have a simple UIViewController whose view is created via a Nib. Here's the structure of the Nib:

[image]

And a screenshot of the layout:

[image]

Whatever the previous view (there are 2 possibilities), there is significant stutter/lag when transitioning to this view. Even the keyboard animation is lagged. Also, this is **only on an actual device**.

I've tried removing the MKMapView to see if that was the case, but it didn't make a difference.

Is the Nib too complex? Should I load everything via code? I'm not sure what it could be, but its really annoying, especially when the rest of the app is super crisp.

As far as code goes, its nothing special: just alloc/init a view, push it onto a UINavigationController, etc. Nothing in the viewWillAppear:/viewWillDisappear:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from Reddit, where you posted code (probably want to do that here too):

My guess would be the lag is coming from the section from line 44 through 80ish, where you build the overlay. Something in there might be taking longer than you think (Spotpoint unSerialize sounds fishy). You typically want to do as little work as possible in viewDidLoad, since that is called as the UI is transitioning to the new view controller.

Try throwing that code into a GCD queue or running it in the background, and see if that helps the loading stutter.